# Validar inputs según el valor total ingresado con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Espero puedan ayudarme, tengo dos funciones donde utilizo jquery, hago la suma de dos inputs **"hombres y mujeres"** que hacen el total del personal de una escuela, abajo de ellos otros cuatro donde se pone la cantidad de personas según sus funciones, pero estas deben concordar con el total de hombres y mujeres que se especifico con anterioridad, para esto creo una función que hace la suma de hombres y mujeres que son el total de ´personal y el resultado se lo envió a la otra función.

FUNCION DE SUMA HOBRES Y MUJERES QUE DAN EL TOTAL

```js
//FUNCION QUE ESCUCHA EL CAMBIO EN LOS INPUT DE HOMBRES Y MUJERES QUE LABORAN
    $('.inputTotalPer').keyup(function() {
      var totalpersonal = 0;
    
      //console.log('valor enviado de la primer fucnion'+ totalpersonal);
      //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
      $(".inputTotalPer").each(function() {
        if (Number($(this).val())) {
          totalpersonal = totalpersonal + Number($(this).val());
        }
      });
      $("#total").val(totalpersonal);
      //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
      totalPersonal(totalpersonal);
    });
```

FUNCIÓN QUE SUMA LOS CAMPOS DE PERSONAL POR ACTIVIDAD Y COMPARA CON EL PARÁMETRO DE LA PRIMER FUNCIÓN

```js
function totalPersonal(dato) {
  $('.input_form4').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;

    console.log('dato que llega'+ dato);
    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $(".input_form4").each(function() {
      if (Number($(this).val())) {
        total = total + Number($(this).val());
        console.log('suma segunda funcion'+ total);
        if(total > dato){
          alert('La suma de los campos por función no concuerda con el total del personal');
          $(".input_form4").val('');
        }
      }
    });
    $("#subtotal").val(total);
    //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
  });
}
```

la suma se hace correctamente, pero al momento de enviar el valor la primera vez lo hace bien, pero si modifico un valor de hombres o mujeres el nuevo valor de la suma ya no lo toma en cuenta, no se que estoy haciendo mal,espero puedan ayudarme.

NOTA: Dichas funciones se ejecutan al escribir nuevo valor

**EJEMPLO:**

```js
//FUNCION QUE ESCUCHA EL CAMBIO EN LOS INPUT DE HOMBRES Y MUJERES QUE LABORAN
$('.inputTotalPer').keyup(function() {
  var totalpersonal = 0;

  //console.log('valor enviado de la primer fucnion'+ totalpersonal);
  //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
  $(".inputTotalPer").each(function() {
    if (Number($(this).val())) {
      totalpersonal = totalpersonal + Number($(this).val());
    }
  });
  $("#total").val(totalpersonal);
  //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
  totalPersonal(totalpersonal);
});

//FUNCION QUE HACE LA SUMA  DE LOS CAMNPOS POR FUNCION QUE DESEMPEÑAN Y COMPARA CON EL TOTAL DE HOMBRES Y MUJERES
function totalPersonal(dato) {
  $('.input_form4').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;

    console.log('dato que llega'+ dato);
    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $(".input_form4").each(function() {
      if (Number($(this).val())) {
        total = total + Number($(this).val());
        console.log('suma segunda funcion'+ total);
        if(total > dato){
          alert('La suma de los campos por función no concuerda con el total del personal');
          $(".input_form4").val('');
        }
      }
    });
    $("#subtotal").val(total);
    //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span><strong>17.</strong> CANTIDAD DE PERSONAS QUE LABORAN EN EL PLANTEL?</span>
        <input id="laboranHombres" class="inputTotalPer" type="text" placeholder="Hombres"  name="laboranHombres" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="laboranMujeres" class="inputTotalPer" type="text" placeholder="Mujeres"  name="laboranMujeres" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/><br>
        <input id="total" class="input_form"  type="text"/>
        <span><strong>18.</strong> CANTIDAD DE PERSONAS SEGUN FUNCIONES QUE DESEMPEÑAN?</span>
        <input id="directivos" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Directivos"  name="directivos" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="docentes" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Docentes"  name="docentes" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="administrativos" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Administrativos"  name="administrativos" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="servicios" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Servicios"  name="servicios" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/><br>
        <input id="subtotal" class="input_form"  type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Antonio, tienes un error de concepto. Te explico, en la función donde sumas los hombres y las mujeres, envías el resultado de la suma a `$("#total")` y después llamas a la función `totalPersonal` y le pasas como parámetro la suma, imagino que para que compruebe que la suma de las actividades no es mayor que el total de personas. Dentro de esa función pones la función que escucha los inputs de actividades y es dentro de esta donde sumas y comparas.
 El problema es el siguiente:
Siempre que ejecutes `totalPersonal` no va a poder comparar nada, porque la comparación está dentro de la función que escucha los inputs y esta sólo se ejecutará al hacerse efectivo el evento keyup, pero es que además estás creando una escucha cada vez que pases por ahí, por tanto si cambias 4 veces las personas, tendrá 4 eventos para el mismo keyup y lo ejecutará 4 veces.
Además y este es el fallo principal, cuando se ejecuta el keyup de los inputs de actividades, solo ejecuta esa parte del código y no la función en la que está contenida y como la variable `dato` viene del principio de la función contenedora dentro del keyup no tiene un valor "actualizado", así que te puede coger cualquier valor que haya tenido.
Solución:
Como guardas en `$("#total")` el valor de la suma de personas, lo cogeremos de ahí para la comparación, ya no hace falta pasarlo como parámetro a ningún sitio. La escucha del keyup para los inputs de actividades, ha de ejecutarse una sola vez, por tanto la ponemos suelta, es decir sin estar dentro de una función. Por último la función `totalPersonal` ahora trabaja independiente, y hace exclusivamente lo que debe hacer.
Saludos.

```js
//FUNCION QUE ESCUCHA EL CAMBIO EN LOS INPUT DE HOMBRES Y MUJERES QUE LABORAN
$('.inputTotalPer').keyup(function() {
    var totalpersonal = 0;

    //console.log('valor enviado de la primer fucnion'+ totalpersonal);
    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $(".inputTotalPer").each(function() {
        if (Number($(this).val())) {
            totalpersonal = totalpersonal + Number($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $("#total").val(totalpersonal);
    //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
    totalPersonal();
});

$('.input_form4').keyup(function() {
    totalPersonal();
});


//FUNCION QUE HACE LA SUMA  DE LOS CAMNPOS POR FUNCION QUE DESEMPEÑAN Y COMPARA CON EL TOTAL DE HOMBRES Y MUJERES
function totalPersonal() {
    var dato = Number($("#total").val());
    var total = 0;

    console.log('dato que llega' + dato);
    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $(".input_form4").each(function() {
        if (Number($(this).val())) {
            total = total + Number($(this).val());
            console.log('suma segunda funcion' + total);
            if (total > dato) {
                alert('La suma de los campos por función no concuerda con el total del personal');
                $(".input_form4").val('');
                total = 0;
            }
        }
        $("#subtotal").val(total);
        //console.log('total sumado en la segunda funcion'+totalP);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span><strong>17.</strong> CANTIDAD DE PERSONAS QUE LABORAN EN EL PLANTEL?</span>
        <input id="laboranHombres" class="inputTotalPer" type="text" placeholder="Hombres"  name="laboranHombres" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="laboranMujeres" class="inputTotalPer" type="text" placeholder="Mujeres"  name="laboranMujeres" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/><br>
        <input id="total" class="input_form"  type="text"/>
        <span><strong>18.</strong> CANTIDAD DE PERSONAS SEGUN FUNCIONES QUE DESEMPEÑAN?</span>
        <input id="directivos" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Directivos"  name="directivos" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="docentes" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Docentes"  name="docentes" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="administrativos" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Administrativos"  name="administrativos" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/>
        <input id="servicios" class="input_form4" type="text" placeholder="Servicios"  name="servicios" pattern="^[0-9]\d*$" title="Ingrese solo numeros positivos"/><br>
        <input id="subtotal" class="input_form"  type="text"/>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias hermano, estaba atorado con esto, agradezco infinitamente tu tiempo para apoyarme y sobre todo con tu explicación, ya que eso es muy importante para mi retroalimentación y comprender el error que estaba cometiendo, de nuevo, GRACIAS.

Comment: Disculpa pero había una llamada a una función (Test) que había creado en el sniplet y me había olvidado de borrarla, ahora el sniplet funciona. Me alegro de que te haya servido la explicación, creo que así es como mejor se aprende. Suerte!!!

Comment: Si me di cuenta y la borre, gracias.